# Variac power on current surge

Tags: power, mains

I am looking into buying a variac from Ebay, but many of the devices on sale are rated for 2 - 3kVA (@220VAC). Now my concern with these devices is that simply turning them on (with or without load) will cause a power huge surge that may blow my home's fuse. Is there a rule of thumb for maximum input current at initial power on?

Comment: Have you considered using the old TV tech's trick of using an incandescent light bulb in series to limit the turn on current transient?  http://www.repairfaq.org/samnew/tvfaq/tvtslbt.htm

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes. I plan to use both as a variac is good at limiting voltage, but not good at limiting current.

Answer (score 2):

Power surges or big inrush current is definitely associated with transformers be they auto or regular. It happens when they are switched on at the zero crossing of the voltage cycle. Yes, I said the zero crossing point. This produces the biggest peak in flux density and if the core saturates too much then the circuit trips.

Convince yourself, by communicating with the supplier, that inrush current is not a problem. By the way, starting a transformer on full load slightly reduces the inrush current problem. It's not prima facea gut-feeling logic but it's true

Comment: Starting at full load defeats the whole purpose I need the variac for, so that is no option.

Comment: That was only a btw statement, buying a variac that doesn't magnetically saturate is the trick or, activating it with a peak  voltage detect switch if unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Variacs used to be common in school labs. I have never seen one trip a breaker or fuse. Plus, most Variacs have a replaceable fuse.

Please note that the Variac circuit can be quite dangerous. With the switch in the OFF position, only one side of the transformer output (the tap) is turned off. The neutral or return wire is still ON and runs straight to the power line. Since ground isn't ground in most buildings, the output can shock. Also older Variacs will have old style non-polarized power plugs and fit an outlet either way so that the un-switched side can be the "hot" AC line.

Comment: I have a 30A variac that *occasionally* trips the 15A breaker it's connected to. It seems to be somewhat dependent on the instantaneous voltage when the connection is made, but I haven't messed with it much (it's a pain enough to reset the breaker).